# XTC file reading error

Tags: c, unix, gcc, structure, bioinformatics

```
#include "xdrfile/xdrfile_xtc.h"
#include "xdrfile/xdrfile.h"
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{   
    int nat;
    int step;
    float time;
    float prec;
    int status;
    matrix box;
    rvec k[3];
    XDRFILE* xfp=xdrfile_open("test2.xtc","r");
    status=read_xtc(xfp,nat,&step,&time,box,k,&prec);
    xdrfile_close(xfp); 
    return 0;
}
```

I tried to run the code using the xtc library to read a trajectory frame of GROMACS... I am getting an error,

```
Segmentation error
```

Can you please help???

Comment: Have you tried running in a debugger to locate *where* in your code the crash happens?

Comment: I'd start adding `if (xfp == NULL) { perror("Error!"); return 1;}` before to read data.

Comment: just included the "if" step... Nothing different happens... Segmentation fault still...

Comment: What is `read_xtc`? i cannot find anything about it..

Comment: It's actually a function to read xtc files of GROMACS... Defined in external header file...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at [this code](http://svn.cgl.ucsf.edu/svn/chimera/trunk/libs/Trajectory/formats/Gromacs/_gromacs/_gromacsmodule.cpp)

Second parameter `nat` must be set to a value retrieved `read_xtc_natoms` function. The value must be initialized anyway.

Moreover the array `k` width must match the `nat` value.

```
#include "xdrfile/xdrfile_xtc.h"
#include "xdrfile/xdrfile.h"
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int nat;
    int step;
    float time;
    float prec;
    int status;
    matrix box;
    int status;

    char fileName[] = "test2.xtc";

    status = read_xtc_natoms(fileName, &nat);

    if (status != exdrOK)
    {
        XDRFILE* xfp = xdrfile_open(fileName, "r");
        if (xfp != NULL)
        {
            rvec k[nat];
            status = read_xtc(xfp, nat, &step, &time, box, k, &prec);
            xdrfile_close(xfp);
        }
        else
        {
            perror("File not opened:");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "read_xtc_natoms failure; return code %d", status);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

In the above code I used [VLAs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html) to create the k array, but you can use dynamic memory too:

```
#include "xdrfile/xdrfile_xtc.h"
#include "xdrfile/xdrfile.h"
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int nat;
    int step;
    float time;
    float prec;
    int status;
    matrix box;
    int status;

    char fileName[] = "test2.xtc";

    status = read_xtc_natoms(fileName, &nat);

    if (status != exdrOK)
    {
        rvec *k = malloc(nat * sizeof(rvec));

        if (k != NULL)
        {
            XDRFILE* xfp = xdrfile_open(fileName, "r");
            if (xfp != NULL)
            {
                status = read_xtc(xfp, nat, &step, &time, box, k, &prec);
                xdrfile_close(xfp);
            }
            else
            {
                perror("File not opened:");
            }

            free(k);
        }
        else
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error in dynamic allocation of k vector\n");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "read_xtc_natoms failure; return code %d", status);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes... It is compiling successfully and giving the correct output... Can you please explain what was my problem???

Comment: As I wrote yje read_xtc function wants an array, and the array width must match the number of elements retrieved using `read_xtc_natoms` function. In your code you created an array to small to be fitted with all data from your file, so when read function try to write out of bounds of passed array it explode with segmentation fault