# SIGSEGV in C extension for Python

Tags: linux, python-3.x, pointers, segmentation-fault, python-c-extension

I have a C extension module for Python that reads an xtc trajectory using the function _xdr_read_xtc.

The module is built into a .so library without problems and it runs fine most of the time. However, sometimes I get 'Segmentation fault (core dumped)'.

```
static PyObject * _xdr_read_xtc(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
    int natoms;
    XDRFILE *xd;
    xd = (XDRFILE *) malloc(sizeof(XDRFILE));
    if (xd == NULL){
      return NULL;}

    XDRFILE *dummy;
    dummy = xd;

    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "ii", &xd, &natoms)){
        return NULL;
    }

    free(dummy);

    int step = 0;
    float time;
    float prec;
    matrix box;
    rvec *x;
    x = malloc(natoms * sizeof(*x));
    if (x == NULL){
        return NULL;}

    // read frame
    int status = read_xtc(xd, natoms, &step, &time, box, x, &prec);

    if (status == 0 | status == 11){
        npy_intp dims[2]= {natoms, 3};

        PyArrayObject *matout = (PyArrayObject *) PyArray_SimpleNewFromData(2, dims, NPY_FLOAT, x);
        PyArray_ENABLEFLAGS(matout, NPY_ARRAY_OWNDATA);

        PyObject *Frame = Py_BuildValue("Oii", matout, status, step);
        Py_DECREF(matout);

        return Frame;
    }
    else{
        free(x);
        return  NULL;
    }
}
```

When debugging with Valgrind I get 'Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV). Access not within mapped region at address 0x195688988' in line:

```
int status = read_xtc(xd, natoms, &step, &time, box, x, &prec);
```

Is there anything obviously wrong with the code? An invalid pointer maybe? Or could it be a memory issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Would [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42154502/8051589) help? I think `xd` (first parameter) must be a file that is opened with `xdrfile_open` and `natoms` (second parameter)  must be initilized by `read_xtc_natoms`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I had already check that post, and the xd and natoms arguments that I'm passing are the results of xdrfile_open and read_xtc_natoms functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You allocate memory in `xd` to hold an `XDRFILE`. Then you move `xd` to `dummy`, parse an integer (file handle ?) and put in into `xd`/`dummy`. Then you free `xd` by freeing `dummy`. Then you call `read_xtc(xd, ...` which will access the free'd memory. In case your memory allocator decided to let go of that page, you get a SIGSEGV.

Move the `free(dummy)` to where you actually no longer need the memory.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
What I was trying to do with dummy was to fix a memory leak, I don't actually use it for anything (or at least I didn't mean to). If I print out the address of the variables I get the following: 
xd after malloc: 0000000000572910
dummy: 0000000000572910
xd after ParseTuple: 0000000000572790
dummy after ParseTuple: 0000000000572910
I will try moving the free(dummy), but I don't think it's causing the problem.

Comment: `xd` is leaked in the error path of `x = malloc(...`, and both arms of `if (status...`. Don't just copy the value of `xd` to `dummy` and then free `dummy` - you will actually free `xd`.
AFAICS you need to use `xdrfile_open()` to open the file, which will return an `XDRFILE`, which in turn is definitely not an integer you can put through `ParseTuple`. You may find [this](http://svn.cgl.ucsf.edu/svn/chimera/trunk/libs/Trajectory/formats/Gromacs/_gromacs/_gromacsmodule.cpp) helpful.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer since the link was very helpful!